# MVC 3 Login Page cannot get the theme files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my MVC 3 project i have a template with jquery + css files. In authorized pages there is no problem i can use all these files and the template. But in the login page there is a problem with linking the files.

File structure is like this :

- MVC project root

  - assets
  - js
  - css

and in _Layout.cshtml, linking is like this:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("../../assets/css/main.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("../../assets/scripts/spinner/jquery.mousewheel.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../assets/scripts/spinner/ui.spinner.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("../../assets/scripts/fileManager/elfinder.min.js")"></script>
```

But in firebug i got an error like this:

Syntax error:    localhost/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"

Application looks for a different path. How can i do it?

Thanks

---

In my example code you can see that i used it :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but no hope. In firebug i can see that page tries to load jquery.js from "/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/Script/jquery.js".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding a route to ignore javascript/css files, so in `RegisterRoutes` in your Global.asax, you could add the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*js}", new { js = @".*\.js(/.*)?"});
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*css}", new { css = @".*\.css(/.*)?"});
```

However, if you are using the built in authentication and have an authorization node that looks something like:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
<system.web>
```

Then .NET will automatically deny requests for any file mapped to .NET for unauthenticated users. You'd therefore need to allow access to the scripts folder by using a location node:

```
<location path="scripts">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Seeing as you are using MVC, it might be easier to use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) on a controller action rather than using the authorization node within the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `../..` in your hrefs with `~`

All your urls inside `@Url.Content("...")` should start with a tilde.

Answer (score 1):

You should config your web folder's security, add

> **IUSR**

,

> **IIS_IUSRS**

and assign them with read and execute permission.